# Error while merging two tables - what is error int this code please help me

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table product
(
    product_id int, 
    product_name varchar(20), 
    rate int
);

insert into product 
values (1, 'Tea', 22), (2, 'Coffee', 30), (3, 'Muffin', 67);

create table updated_products 
(
    product_id int, 
    product_name varchar(100), 
    rate int
); 

insert into updated_products 
values (1, 'tea', 10), (2, 'coffee', 20), (3, 'muffin', 30);

select * from product;
select * from updated_products;

merge product t 
using updated_products s on (t.product_id = s.product_id)
when matched then
update set t.product_name = s.product_name, t.rate = s.rate 
when not matched by t then 
insert (product_id, product_name, rate) values (s.product_id, s.product_name, s.rate);

select * from product;
```

I get a syntax error in `merge`

Comment: when not matched by t  please replace with when not matched

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/F7iUq42C

Comment: Also see [so you want to use merge, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge) and [this pattern that avoids a variety of issues with merge](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern). Your scenario is a trivial upsert and doesn't really justify the use of merge IMHO. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/gVb2Y2U4).

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/

Comment: I am using this compiler in this its showing error @Sergey

Comment: Stop using online SQL compiler tools that aren't made for SQL Server. Run your queries _against SQL Server_. I have no idea what engine that free web thingy is for but it can't even parse `SELECT GETDATE();`.

Answer (score 2):

I would honestly avoid `MERGE` altogether, as this scenario is just not complex enough to justify dealing with [all of its problems](https://sqlblog.org/merge).

A better `UPSERT` pattern, IMHO, unless you are solely looking at character count, comes from [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) and is what we did before `MERGE` and will continue to use until `MERGE` is fully fixed:

```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 
  UPDATE p WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) 
    SET p.product_name = u.product_name, p.rate = u.rate
  FROM dbo.product AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.updated_products AS u
    ON p.product_id = u.product_id;
 
  INSERT dbo.product(product_id, product_name, rate)
    SELECT product_id, product_name, rate
    FROM dbo.updated_products AS u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.product AS p
        WHERE p.product_id = u.product_id
    );
 
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

- Working [db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/gVb2Y2U4).

As an aside, if you're going to use some free online web SQL compiler thing, make sure it's built for the actual database platform you're using, *and check its work against that platform*. Telling a SQL Server expert "your suggestion is wrong" because some tool made for a completely different platform told you so is... well, not very respectful.